# Баннер AdMob в эмуляторе

Tags: android, admob

Можно ли загрузить баннер в AdView в эмуляторе? Почему-то не получается это сделать.

содержимое layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="здесь реальный id"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Данный код, взятый из офиц. доков google, почему то ничего не загружает:

```
                AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Но следующий код, работает:

```
 AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Загрузить баннер можно. В коде у вас всё верно. Может у вас интернета на эмуляторе нет? Или разрешения на интернет соединения в манифесте...
Выложите что там вам logCat выдаёт.

Comment: проблема была в размерах загружаемого баннера, logcat показал ошибку